# How to search for products by UPC using python bindings for Ebay's findItemsByProduct API?

Tags: python, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I'm trying to find products by UPC using [EBay's Product Find Items by Product ID](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsByProduct.html), specifically using the [Python bindings](https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python).

I'm trying:

```py
    api = Connection(
        appid='my id', config_file=None)

    response = api.execute('findItemsByProduct', {
        'productId': 820103794923,
        'itemFilter': [
            {'name': 'MinQuantity', 'value': 1},
```

But I get:

```
{'ack': 'Failure', 'errorMessage': {'error': {'errorId': '4', 'domain': 'Marketplace', 'severity': 'Error', 'category': 'Request', 'message': 'Product ID is required.', 'subdomain': 'Search'}}, 'version': '1.13.0', 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 24, 21, 46, 52)}
```

Whats the correct argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
api = Connection(config_file=yaml_path)
response = api.execute('findItemsByProduct', 
                   '<productId type="ReferenceID">820103794923</productId><itemFilter><name>MinQuantity</name><value>1</value></itemFilter>')
response.reply
```

{'ack': 'Success', 'version': '1.13.0', 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 26, 10, 13, 10), 'searchResult': {'_count': '0'}, 'paginationOutput': {'pageNumber': '0', 'entriesPerPage': '100', 'totalPages': '0', 'totalEntries': '0'}, 'itemSearchURL': 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/?_samilow=1&_LH_MIL=1&_ddo=1&_ipg=100&_pgn=1&_productid=820103794923'}